# Dapp react frontend code stop execution after transaction signed by metamask

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, metamask, nft

I have a simple react frontend application using web3 to mint my ERC721 contract NFTs. I am using metamask to sign transactions when calling functions on my smart contract.

My code works when I call the minting function to mint a new NFT. But any code after the 'const tx = ...' line does not execute in the below code snippet inside the "mint" function. I get the metamask window asking to confirm the transaction.

I can see that a new NFT was minted when I check the NFT count using truffle console. My code is below. Not sure why js code after sending the confirmation does not work. Any help on this much appreciated. Currently I am using ganache-cli to deploy my smart contract.

I included portions of my full code below. I included the constructor function and the mint function. The other functions not shown setup the connection to metmask provider and define an instance of web3 using metamask provider.

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Web3 from "web3";
import detectEthereumProvider from "@metamask/detect-provider";

class NftComponent extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            account:'',
            contract:null,
            addressToMintNft:'',
            Nftcount:null,
            web3Local: null
        }
    }
//rest of the functions        
        .........
        .........
        .........

        mint = async (addressTo, count) => {

        console.log('Address to which NFT will be minted :');
        console.log(addressTo);

        console.log('Number of NFTs requested to be minted is');
        console.log(count);


        const tx = await this.state.contract.methods.mint(addressTo, count).send({from: this.state.account})

        console.log('Transaction from calling mint function is:');
        console.log(tx);

    }
```